# Using .json,.csv,etc. files in D3

Tags: javascript, python, json, csv, d3.js

Since I'm new to D3, this is something I just got started with (until now, I wrote my own data, ten random number for example), and I need some help.

What is the proper way to "call" for these files with, for example, d3.json ?
Do I have to name the whole path of the file (C:/Users/Desktop,etc)? What to do after that?

If I create a local server using Python and Windows' Command Prompt, and get the file in there, how do I "call" it with D3? Just copy the adress, or do I need to do something else?

I started learning D3 recently, and it's not hard, but this is something I can't figure out, and I can't check if I've done something correctly if I don't have any data to test it with.

Comment: I highly suggest you to read these tutorials: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3

Answer (score 0):

For the short answer, here is the code for parsing csv file:

```
d3.csv("file_path.csv", function (data) {
    // Your data is now in the 'data' variable and can be used inside this scope.
    // Normally all your stuffs going here. You shouldn't put any drawing outside of this scope
    // because d3.csv is an asynchronous function and it will return immediately.
    // So you have to do all the thing in this callback function so that the data has been loaded already.
});
```

For long answer, and further options, I think you should read this article: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV

It's pretty much the same like above for d3.tsv, d3.json.

So wih the path for the csv file:
assuming that you have your server running at `http://localhost/`, and your csv file is under the folder `data` on the server; so your path to your csv files will be `"data/filename.csv", and put this path to the d3.csv argument.